# SolrNet queries with boost functions

Tags: solrnet

I'm trying to use this library (which looks very nice) but I'm having difficulty understanding how to add extra params to my queries such as boost functions etc. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ExtraParams property of QueryOptions to add any parameter to the Solr querystring. Example:

```
ISolrOperations<Document> solr = ...
var results = solr.Query("myquery", new QueryOptions {
  ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"bf", "recip(rord(myfield),1,2,3)^1.5"}
  }
});
```