# Solrnet - Boost query with function

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am trying to query sol using solrnet.

I am looking to boost the query by a record's property.

My query then looks like this:
/select?fl=QualityScore,score&q={!boost+b=sum(1,log(sum(1,QualityScore)))+v=$qq}&qq="qome query"

Is there a way to do this using SolrNet?

PS - I already looked at [SolrNet queries with boost functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577074/solrnet-queries-with-boost-functions) and I dont see the same result when I use 'bf'.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying#LocalParams

Comment: @Mauricio - this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks - maybe you should have added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mauricio's pointer is what helped me in this case.

[Local Params](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md#localparams)

Comment: The link is dead. :(